# Visual Studio build on Remote Desktop

Tags: visual-studio, build, remote-desktop, pause

I have an odd problem. I'm working on a remote computer with Visual Studio. As long as I am on the remote computer the build of the solution works fine (~70" secs).

But...

If I start to build the solution and get back to my computer, the build is like "pausing". When I get back to the remote computer after 5'-6' mins, the build resumes and completes.

Any ideas???????
Thnx